# Check for prime in a list using sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I have an array as an input and i want to print the prime numbers that exist in that list. I was able to do that using `trial division method`. But I am struck at a point while trying to do the same thing using sieve of `Eratosthenes method`.

I tried it with below code, but got confused on how to compare the end result array with my input array list and return only those values that matches the input list. ( Detailed answer would be helpful as am a beginner in javascript).

```
var arr=[4,7,10,12,13,19,22,37];
function checkPrime(arr)
{
  var output=[],primes=[];
  var x=arr.length;
  for(i=2;i<=arr[x-1];i++)
    primes[i]=1;

  for(i=2;i<=arr[x-1];i++)
    for(j=2;j<=Math.sqrt(arr[x-1]);j++)
      primes[i*j]=0;


  for(i=0;i<=arr[x-1];i++){
    if(primes[i]==1){
      output.push(i);
     }
    }



  return output;
}

console.log(checkPrime(arr));
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?  Do you get any output?

Comment: for the above arr input, i get the output [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37], but i want to check whether that exists in my input arr and then print only those that exists in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your output list, you want to compare against the values in arr, not the indices, so you need to replace `primes[i]` with `primes[arr[i]]`.

So this:

```
if (primes[i] == 1) {
  output.push(i);
}
```

Becomes this:

```
if (primes[arr[i]] == 1) {
  output.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: @ShankarGuru It's always the smallest things that give us the largest headaches :)